# Bootstrap 3 Default validation plugin

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi guys please do check on this code

The validation partly works but just on the required field, the range length doesn't seem to work. Can you please help me ? THanks!

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var Username = $("#Username");
    var Password = $("#Password");
    var LoginForm = $('#LoginForm');
    var SubmitBtn = $('#SubmitBtn');

    LoginForm.validate();

    Username.rules("add", {
        required: true,
        rangelength: [3, 20],
        messages: {
            required: "You must provide your username.",
            rangelength: "The user name must be between 3 and 20 characters in length."
        }
    });
    Password.rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "You must provide your password."
        }
    });

    $('#LoginForm').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $('#SubmitBtn').prop('disabled', true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hTPY7/476/

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't come with any core validation plugins. What you're seeing in your fiddle is the HTML5 basic validation, which has been enabled with the attribute `required="required"`.

Comment: See http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a reference to [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Bootstrap has no validation plugin.

You can reference Jquery Validate from Microsoft's CDN if you want.

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js

You rule is OK:

```
Username.rules("add", {
      required: true,
      rangelength: [3, 20],
      messages: {
        required: "You must provide your username.",
        rangelength: "The user name must be between 3 and 20 characters in length."
      }
    });
```

Here's it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/3F5Sf/1/

Comment: What tooltip you're talking about? Are you using Bootstrap tooltip plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips on your page?

Comment: I think the OP wants to have error messages inside  `<span class="help-block"></span>`